# Create a new Google Sheet in a specific drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script

Using a standalone script, I want to create a new sheet in a given folder.

```
function criaSheet(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('ID');
  folder.createFile('new Spreadsheet', '', MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS)
}
```

This code asks me to use Google Advanced Services, which one?

And this code creates the sheet in the root folder:

```
function criaSheet(){
    SpreadsheetApp.create('mySheet')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to create a new spreadsheet file, then move it to the folder, then delete the original:

```
function createNewFile(){
  var newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create('AAAA11111');
  var newID = newSS.getId();

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('your folder ID');
  var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newID);

  newFile.makeCopy(folder);

  //Delete original file
  DriveApp.removeFile(newFile);
};
```

`DriveApp.removeFile()` seems to be removing the file without sending it to the trash.  Which is fine by me, but Google Drive seems to be doing some weird stuff lately.  From the Drive "Details" section, I can open the deleted file, even though there is no trace of it anywhere in any of my folders, including the trash.

If you want to try to figure out the Advanced Drive Service:

In the script editor, choose the Resources menu and Advanced Google Services.

[image: AdvancedGoogleServices]

Then turn the Drive API on:

[image: Drive API]

Comment: Hi, thanks, the process of create, copy, delete worked perfectly! I didn't need to use the Advanced Drive API, the built-in seems to be enough.